# How can I ask, "Will this email address be removed from this mail group?"

Tags: translation, equivalent-phrase

I would like to ask, "Will this email address be removed from this mail group?"

The best I could come up with was, "这邮件地址会这个mail group除了吗？"
How should I ask this?

Comment: 这个邮件地址会被从这个邮件群组中删除吗？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better use active voice in Chinese, e.g. "這個郵件組會刪除這個電郵地址嗎?"

Indeed, I think the real challenge in your question is the two occurrence of "this".  It is really awkward to have two "這個" in the same sentence.  If you provide more information, I think we can make a better translation.

Edit @sazarando : for "Will this email address be removed from the Inside_Sales mail group?", I suggest "這個電郵地址會從'內部銷售'郵件組刪除(掉)嗎?"

(Instead of passive voice, I'd rather omit the subject.)

Comment: OK, how about... "Will this email address be removed from the Inside_Sales mail group?" - I want to ask if a particular mail address is going to be removed from the Inside_Sales mail group or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can say "这个邮件地址会被邮件组删除/移除吗？". First, you need to catch the important words in this sentence. " email address"(邮箱地址),"removed"(移除) and "mail group" (邮件组). You can make a sentence with these three words in a logical order. " will" is future tense, so you need to use "会".

Comment: Could you explain the sentence a little bit? Maybe split it into pieces to explain how you constructed it? It's very low quality as it is.

Answer (score 1):

I think using passive voice is better, ex. "這個郵件地址將會(被)從(郵件)群組中移除嗎". It implies YOU may be going to delete/remote the address from the group.

If you use "這個郵件組會刪除這個電郵地址嗎", it means the GROUP is going to delete/remove the mail address actively.